# Merging or updating table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

At the moment i have two tables, and I´m trying to either merge the two tables into a new one or update the first table with the information of the second.

Table A:

| NAME | LASTNAME | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |

Table B:

| COUNTRY | YEAR |
| --- | --- |

Table C:

| NAME | LASTNAME | CITY | COUNTRY | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

For update It will be the same result but instead of table_C (New table) I would have an update veersion of TABLE_A

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use images to show your problem, rather prefer text. And why are your tables missing relations?

Comment: I belive, this question will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496734/how-to-use-select-into-with-a-join

Comment: Thankl you i will check it out